# Ruby on Rails Migration with Primary and Foreign Key

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am just starting ROR and making different tables for the SQLite database and am running into some trouble in relation to automatically generated id's of tables and foreign keys. To create my tables I used the "rails generate scaffold" command followed by the attributes that I needed. I went to the db/migrate directory and looked at what I had just defined. But I don't understand how I am supposed to explicitly reference foreign keys. I'm used to using Oracle so I'd normally do this process in the very first step during creation and be done with it already.

For example, I have a users table with some general attributes such as a username, password, etc. I also have an orders table with attributes transactionID (auto generated), userID (I want to this to be an FK), PartNo (FK key from the Products table). What I don't understand is how to use the auto generated key from the Users table and include it as a foreign key in the Orders table.

Also, I read somewhere else that if I put a line of code such as

```
t.integer user_id
```

in my create_orders.rb file then it would automatically know that this is a foreign key!?

I feel like this is probably really easy and I'm missing something. This is my first time using rails and I thought I got to define the foreign keys straight away via SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I could figure this out it would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you do this, on your `Order` model, you'd use a `belongs_to :user` to generate the relationship and utilize the foreign key.

If you want to be able to go from `User` to `Order`, you'll likely be a one-to-many, so you'd have to do `has_many :orders` on `User`.

[Here is the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) for associations in Rails.  And [here is the specific documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one) for `belongs_to` vs `has_one`.

Comment: Okay, so if I were to go to my models folder and add has_one :user then I guess I can also do the same and add has_one :product?

Comment: Actually, my answer was backwards. I, like a lot of the Rails community, still get `has_one` and `belongs_to` confused. :)  I'll update the answer for `Product` too.  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

Comment: No problem.  Sorry for the 10 minutes of confusion. :)